# Mule- Access spring property placeholder inside groovy component

Tags: mule

Is there a way I can access spring property placheolder directly inside groovy script file used in a mule Flow

Would something like this work? . Assuming that 'ftp.server.url' is a property in application.properties loaded by spring

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

Ex Groovy script:

```
def ftpClient =new FTPClient().with {
    connect ${ftp.server.url}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is embedded in the Mule XML config, this should work:

```
def ftpClient =new FTPClient().with {
    connect "${ftp.server.url}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. That worked like a charm. Is there a way I can access the properties if the groovy script is in external file.Just curious

Comment: I don't know... have you tried the above with an external file?